# Unable to edit workflow 2010 inside our migrated SharePoint online site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have migrated a SharePoint 2010 site to SharePoint online, and we have a workflow which show correctly inside the list settings >> Workflow, as follow:-

[image]

But when i tried to edit the workflow using SP Designer 2013, i got this error :-
[image]

now i tried to delete the cache from these 3 locations:-

- C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
- C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
- C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

i also tried to edit the workflow from "SP Designer" >> "All Files" >> "Workflow" >> open the ".xmol".

but none of the above fix the issue for me. can anyone advice please?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the issue with SharePoint mismatch, since you have migrated it from SharePoint 2010. Try uninstalling the SharePoint 2013 designer and install it back.... and also see are you able to create any new workflow in the designer. If nothing works you may need to recreate the workflow using SharePoint 2013  designer workflow template. And also make sure you are only using SharePoint 2013 designer.. if you have got installed SharePoint 2010 designer as well, need to uninstall it.

Please verify the below checklist :

1. Uninstall SharePoint Designer 2010 if installed.
2. Uninstall SharePoint Designer 2013.
3. Use Windows Explorer to open these 3 locations and delete all the files there:
           C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
           C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
           C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
4. Reboot the client.
5. Install SharePoint designer 2013 with the latest updates packaged.
6. Open SPD 2013, connect to the site and edit the workflow.

Similar problem is discussed in the below thread :

[SharePoint designer cannot display the item - workflows](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3af1f65a-bbbd-46e3-bae3-eb4529b549d2/sharepoint-designer-cannot-display-the-item-workflows?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

Comment: i do not have SharePoint designer 2010, so i clear the files from the 3 locations >> restart the server (where the SP designer is installed) >> but still facing the same issue. also when i create a new item , the workflow will have this status "Failed To Start" with a correlation error.. any idea? can i export the workflow and re-publish it?

Comment: Try to uninstall sp 2013 designer and re-install it back... it will just take little time.

Comment: so you think the problem is with SP Designer and not the workflow? and if this is the case then why the workflow fail to run..? so seems the problem is within the workflow itself.. is my point valid to you?

Comment: If this was a working workflow in SharePoint 2010, and after migration in online it does not work.... then it could be the problem with version mismatch of the designer tool not with the workflow.... By the way please try this also, create a sample workflow using your present version of designer.

Comment: but if the workflow is fine, then why it is failing to run when creating new items??

Comment: although i were sure that this will not fix my issue, i re-install SP designer 2013 64-bit with SP1 but still i am getting the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

I believe your workflow was built on 2010 template

Comment: yes i think so, it was created by our customer...